# Obtain data from a GET in superagent function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var countElemnts = function() {
            superagent
              .get('/someOtherUrl')
              .query({
                type: value.type
              })
              .end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body));
                if (res.ok) {
                  reply(JSON.stringify(res.body));
                } else {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              })
          };
          superagent
            .post('/someUrl')
            .type('json')
            .send({
              name: 'value.update',
              data: {
                id: request.params.id,
                type: value.type,
                count: countElemnts()
              }
            })
            .end(function() {
              reply({
                message: 'ok'
              });
            });
```

In data option of the send function I'm trying to call a function to obtain some value.

What I want is to get the value that comes in the body of a reply, ie the res.body. Upon console.log get this [{ "count ": 3 } ], but if I do a console.log of res.body.count tells me undefined, what could I do to get the value 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the return exactly this  `[{ "count ": 3 } ]`? If so, the `count` attribute has an extra space at the end and you'll have to retrieve the value like this: `res.body[0]["count "]`

Comment: Thats works perfect, thanks victorkohl,  now when I send the data with post, the count doesn't sent, only sends the name, id and type. Can I use a function like that in that POST? And de returns is exactly like [{"count":3}] with no extra space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the return doesn't have the extra space in `"count "` (as mentioned in the comments) the problem was that you were trying to access the `count` attribute of the array and not the object (first element of the array), so to access it you should do it like:

```
res.body[0].count
```

As for the problem of not being able to get the count in your POST, the problem is that `countElemnts` uses an asynchronous function. The `end` method of superagent takes a function as parameter and it is only called when it receives a response. By that time, your function had already returned (with `undefined`, since you didn't return anything).

You should first make the GET call and then send it to a function that will handle the POST. For example:

```
superagent
.get('/someOtherUrl')
.query({
  type: value.type
})
.end(function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body));
    sendCount(res.body[0].count)
  }
});

function sendCount(count) {
  superagent
  .post('/someUrl')
  .type('json')
  .send({
    name: 'value.update',
    data: {
      //id: request.params.id,  // not sure where you are getting these values from,
      //type: value.type,       // but you should adapt it to your code
      count: count
    }
  })
  .end(function() {
    reply({
      message: 'ok'
    });
  });
}
```